# How can I disable the window next to scrollbar in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I disable the code preview window next to the scrollbar in Intellij?
I am not sure what its name is and cannot find the setting related to it.

[See the red arrow in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgTWV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable or uninstall the CodeGlance plugin under

IntelliJ -> Preferences -> Plugins

Comment: Didn't realize it was a plugin. Thank you very much!